# Errors in cstdint: No member named xxx in global namespace

Tags: c++, macos

What can cause errors like these? I added an empty project to Xcode, added /usr/local/lib  in the Header Search Paths, and added some opencv libraries. Building gave these errors:

[image]

**UPDATE**

It appears stdint.h is indeed installed on my system. I'm running on OS 10.9, so types like `int_least16_t` that xcode can't find in the global namespace do appear to be defined.

`typedef int16_t         int_least16_t;`.

```
find /Applications/Xcode.app -name stdint.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdint.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdint.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/stdint.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdint.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/stdint.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdint.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/stdint.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/5.1/include/stdint.h
```

Comment: Do you also have C++11 support enabled?

Comment: Yes, the C++ Standard Library I'm using is libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support). I'm also using the C++ Language Dialect GNU++11. The same errors occur when using the dialect, C++11. I made sure the compiler I'm using (Apple LLVM 5.1) is indeed using these options.

Comment: Has you verified that you really have `stdint.h` installed in your system and that those types are declared inside it?

Comment: "added /usr/local/lib" — are you sure it's a good idea? Could you have bad stdint.h there? Figure out which stdint.h you are using, whether it has these names mentioned anywhere, and whether other versions you have on your system are different.

Comment: @n.m. You're right. When I removed `/usr/local/lib` from my Header Search Paths, everything worked. The reason I used that path is that it contains opencv libraries I need. How do you recommend I remove the bad libraries, or place the opencv libraries elsewhere?

Comment: It is my firm opinion that installing anything directly under /usr/local is fundamentally broken, because of the ensuing version hell. If you must install from sources, always install under /usr/local/package-name-and-version (softlink to /usr/local/package-name). My choice would be to remove everything under /usr/local and reinstall required packages under their own folders in /usr/local.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to @n.m., I learned that installing anything directly under `/usr/local` is fundamentally broken because of the ensuing version hell. I likely had a some source of badness in `/usr/local/include`, so when I replaced `usr/local/include` with `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.8.2/include/opencv2` (because I installed opencv using brew) in `Xcode > Build Settings > Header Search Paths` (with recursive True) everything worked.